# Having navigation box beside another element

Tags: html, css, formatting

Hey guys I've been trying for days. I'm trying to have a vertical navigation box to the left of a content element. I also need both of these to be centred using margin-left/right:auto.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zfL3C/).

My code is as follows

html

> ```
>   <div class="jobs-formatting">
>       <div class="jobs-links">
>           <ul>
>               <li><a href="renovations.html">Renovations</a></li>
>               <li><a href="remodelling.html">Remodelling</a></li>
>               <li><a href="adding.html">Adding</a></li>
>           </ul>       
>       </div>
>       <div class="body-content-jobs">
>               <h1>Heading</h1>
>               <p>Information</p>
>           </div>
>   </div>
> ```

css

```
.jobs-formatting
{
    background-color:#f96d16;
    height:500px;
    width:1000px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.body-content-jobs
{
    background-color:#5f564d;
    height:500px;
    width:900px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    float:right;
    margin:auto;
}
.jobs-links
{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #5f564d;
    border-left:1px solid #5f564d;
    border-top:1px solid #5f564d;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:Calibri, Times, serif;
    text-align:left;
    margin:auto;
}
```

My overall goal is to have it look something like this;
![]Goal design[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsb1f.png)

With buttons being anything relating to class=jobs-links and with text relating to body-content-jobs. I have both of these inside jobs-formatting.

I've been stuck for a long time and don't even know if its possible so any help would be welcome.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Thats because you have border which makes 100px to 101px; Look for box-sizing http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zfL3C/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your Borders are pushing it down..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJEBq

Lose these^^

```
 border-bottom:1px solid #5f564d;
border-left:1px solid #5f564d;
border-top:1px solid #5f564d;
```

Comment: or just add `* { box-sizing: border-box }` in css :)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/398bf9d0a0996b450eff5c42aeaf1872
It still comes up weird after trying both suggestions.